# Android - Pack resources into apk

Tags: android

Is it possible to pack resources in a way that they get distributed with apk? I know it's impossible to use subfolders in res's directories (drawable, raw, etc)... so I was wondering if I can create folder (data) and somehow tell compiler to include all resources from that folder - and later access them with InputStream (without using R.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that comes close to fitting your description is to use the `assets/` directory in your project. Everything in there (including subdirectories) gets bundled into the APK and can be accessed at runtime via an `AssetManager`.